# Duplicate id, tag null, with another fragment for androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-xml, androidx, android-jetpack

**Issue**
I am trying to add a fragment in activity, along with Navigation. But I see the following error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.myapp/com.app.myapp.HomeMainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #12: Duplicate id 0x7f0900ed, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
```

**Code**

1. activity_home_new.xml

   ```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
         <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
           tools:context=".HomeMainActivity">

           <fragment
           android:id="@+id/my_nav_host_fragment"
           android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="0dp"
           app:defaultNavHost="true"
           app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
           app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
          </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

          </layout>
   ```

No changes made in Fragment and Activity class.

**Solution which I tried**

I tried changing fragment to framelayout and FragmentContainerView in ctivity_home_new.xml The app doesn't; crash.

**My opinion about the crash**

The crash is something related to with "androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment".
There are few questions something similar that is related to MapFragment.

**Not looking for the code, I just want to know the root cause for the crash**

Comment: Did you found any solutions?

Comment: @FlorescuCătălin I think I found it.

Answer (score 22):

It seems that NavHostFragment is just a coincidental passwalker. This problem is related to inflating XML content twice.

In my case what I was doing:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivitySigninBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signin)
}
```

and it was working until I split my content into more fragments. The fix was:

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivitySigninBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root) // Notice the binding root
}
```

Hope it helps, spend some time to figure it out.

Comment: Well, yesterday i've managed to fix it too. I was doing the same process, setting the layout twice.

Comment: Bro. May a higher power bless you. I had spent like 2 hours trying to figure out the error. Managed to comment out   //  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) and retain the second setContentView() fun() and its now working.

Comment: This can be overlooked easily when enabling binding on an existing activity. The error message is not clear enough but this is really the cause and the solution.

Comment: The same reason for me too. One inflate was via the class constructor: `MainActivity: AppCompatActivity(R.layout.activity_main)` and the second via `MainActivityBinding.inflate`.

Answer (score 0):

if your binding object is lateinit :

```
        if (!this::binding.isInitialized) {
            binding = FragmentMainBinding.inflate(context.inflater())
        }
```

else if you are use nullable binding object use this code :

```
        if (binding == null) {
            binding = FragmentMainBinding.inflate(context.inflater())
        }
```

Hope it helps, spend some time to figure it out.
reinflating create this problem !